# Duplicate Random Numbers from Java Secure Random

Tags: java, random

I am expecting unique random numbers from the following `Callable`:

```
public class UniqueGenerator implements Callable<Integer> {

    private static SecureRandom rnd;

    static {
        try {
            rnd = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            rnd.setSeed(UUID.randomUUID().toString().getBytes());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        return rnd.nextInt();

    }
}
```

However from 1,000,000 executions of this method i never get 1,000,000 unique integers.
Is there any way i can ever get the desired result?
What mistake(s) have i made when attempting to generate unique Integers?

Comment: Of course they're not unique. They're random.

Comment: Yep; your problem is that you're expecting something that a random number generator is not designed to do. It could return a 1 every time (unlikely, but possible), and that would still be random. If you want unique numbers, you're going to need a different algorithm entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want 1,000,000 unique random integers, create an `ArrayList` with `Integer` objects from 0 to 999,999 and then shuffle that list using your `SecureRandom` object:

```
Collections.shuffle(cards, secureRandom);
```

Then consume the integers as you need them and recreate the list if it's empty.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, I feel yours is the only approach I need to take to get my desired result

Answer (score 1):

Of course they won't be unique.  They'll be random.  It's perfectly cromulent for the psuedo random number generator to spit back out the same number that it's already produced.  If you run it long enough, like 2^32 times, you will not get 2^32 unique numbers.  Many numbers will be repeated.  If you want unique, random values, UUIDs are a good start (although they are not guaranteed to be unique - the are for all practical purposes.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a million unique numbers in random order, I would use [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29). For example,

```
List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000 * 1000; i++) {
  al.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(al);
// al contains 1,000,000 numbers in random order.
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the Birthday paradox. Your interger has 4294967296 possible value. Let's say 4 billions for the sake of simplicity. You are generating 1 million random integer. That means each of these random integer as roughly 1 chance on 4000 to have randomly the same value as another one. That seam small, but it is for one integer, and you have 999999 other cases to test. The maths behind this are a bit complexe, but let's just say that the chances to get duplicates are almost of 1/1.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: In fact, there was a paper written back in the 1980's that pointed out that by the time you sampled 3*sqrt(RAND_MAX) the probability of seeing a duplicate for random numbers would be greater than 0.99, and that this could be used to show that PRNGs which used their state as the output are not random. In this case, 3*sqrt(2^32) is about 200_000, so OP should definitely see some duplicates if the PRNG is any good.

Comment: its more likely than that, as i employ Math.abs() on the resulting random number, so i only get positive integers.